# odd look CSS drop-down menu

Tags: html, css

I have the following drop down menu: http://jsfiddle.net/fE4YH/

The problem is that the drop-down menu items don't align to the right, they are somewhere in the middle.  Is there an easy way to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have editted your code..just change text-align:right to float:right;

```
#nav li ul li
   {
   font-size:12px;
   font-family: 'MankSans-Bold','Trebuchet MS',arial,sans-serif;
   text-transform: lowercase;
   float:right;
   margin-right:0;
   padding-right:0;
   }
```

It Seems to Work..

Comment: Nice.  I spent so much time on this, don't know why text-align had a problem.  Thanks for the fix.

Answer (score 0):

You could change to width:auto from width:12 em here:

```
   #nav li ul {
   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 orange;
   left: -999em;
   position: absolute;
   width: auto;
   margin-right:-20px;
   padding-right:-20px;
   }
```

And add clear:both here:

```
  #nav li ul li
   {
   font-size:12px;
   font-family: 'MankSans-Bold','Trebuchet MS',arial,sans-serif;
   text-transform: lowercase;
   text-align:right;
   margin-right:0;
   padding-right:0;
   clear:both;
   }
```

And it'll work across browsers.